# Camera streaming using RTP from Android to PC

Tags: android, stream, camera, vlc, rtp

I'd like to write an application for Android for camera streaming to PC (H.263, MPEG_4). I found some libraries: sipandroid, jlibrtp. 
SIPandroid:
RTP packets are streamed (wireshark catches it on PC well), but VLC can't play it.

Jlibrtp:
API is shady, stream is not played correctly using VLC.

May be there are some adaptations to these libraries (to make it working for camera streaming), or there are some other libraries with clean API and samples?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: What client app/protocol/api do you want to use? Is VLC the target, or just a test?

Comment: If you have problems recieving stram on vlc, check the network interfaces. Get stream from all interfaces eg. udp://@:2000 - udp(legacy) stream all interfaces port 2000.

Comment: What do you mean by "stream is not played correctly"? Also, have you checked the VLC messages window for more info?

Answer (score 4):

[VLC has](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html) [built-in support for RTP](http://wiki.videolan.org/RTP), and as @Lukas said, the network interfaces are likely the problem on VLC. If you stream everything to one port, and listen on that port, you will at least get something. You can also look into the RTP packets to see if they are well formed.

VLC itself uses the [LiveMedia](http://wiki.videolan.org/LiveMedia) library, so you may be able to use that.